# Why are there cracks on my ceiling beneath my skylight?

Tags: ceiling, crack, skylight

I have 2x Skylights in my kitchen. On the ceiling directly beneath one of them, there is some pretty nasty cracks/paint bubbling occurring.
There were very small cracks present prior to the installation of the new Velux Skylights, that the contractor started would not grow, as any potential moisture or water issue would be solved with the new skylights.
Long story short, the crack(s) and bubbling have spread.
I have applied drywall putty to the area before, but the issue keeps happening.
Any ideas?
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

What you have may be the results of a leak having been repaired.

Water will swell wood.  If you apply a surface repair to the cracks, then the wood dries and shrinks, you will have a crack again.

The pic also looks as if the compound was possibly applied rather thick, resulting in cracks as it dried. That is common if drywall compound is too thick.

I would leave everything alone for a few days. Preferably wait through a rainstorm, as well as a period of dry days.  Observe the cracks for any change.  If none are observed, you can ascertain that the skylight or roof around it are not leaking. The wood has dried and will be reasonably stable.  Then patch the crack/s.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a leak somewhere in the skylight system or the surrounding area where the flashing attaches to the roof and skylight. Shylights are nice but it seems like they all eventually leak.

Comment: Thank You, so even though I have never seen water physically dripping from the ceiling in that area (even during prolonged downpours) this is still indicative of a leak somewhere?

Comment: @Kyle987  Unfortunately, never seeing water dripping doesn't mean there's no leaks. It can be a very small leak, a few drips per minute, and the water will get absorbed by the insulation and plaster/drywall.  That area to the right of the crack looks like it was /is wet but might be the shading from the picture.  If you can get up into the attic, you might be able to assess the problem further.